# Атрибут stdDeviation у фильтра feGaussianBlur выполняется по разному в разных браузерах

Tags: svg, svg-filter

Размытие  работает по разному во всех браузерах, основанных на Blink (это Chrome, Opera, Ms Edge) и Firefox. Работать в них начинает только в случае, если stdDeviation поставить в значении выше 0.7.
Но размытие на маленьком, по размеру элементе становится слишком большим.

Как его заменить? Или может есть другой фильтр с матрицей и т.п.?

```html
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" style="margin:9px;">
<defs>
<filter id="blur" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.8" in="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>

<symbol id="tt" viewBox="0 0 18 18" filter="url(#blur)"><path d="M8,2H9L15,8V9L9,15H8L2,9V8zM1,1L16,16M1,16L16,1" fill="none" stroke="#14c"/></symbol>
</defs>
<use href="#tt"/>
</svg>
</body>
```

На картинке ниже сравнивается, как выглядит размытие на разных браузерах при одинаковом значении атрибута `stdDeviation`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли решение данной проблемы?
Может использовать другие фильтры или комбинацию фильтров?

Вопрос сформирован из [вопросов](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56018932#56018932) в SVG-чате участника [@Bharatha](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/297453/bharatha)

Comment: Я тебе очень советую удалить этот вопрос потому что ты не понимая всех тонкостей моих задач не знаешь всей сути. Я хочу сам задать этот вопрос. И такой фильтр (твой ответ ниже) я уже применял. Он мне не подходит, т.к. линии сильно размыты и их не видно во всех браузерах на Blink движке, если залить голубым цветом середину. Так что пожалуйста удали вопрос, а я его задам от себя. Благодарю за помощь, время и понимание.

Comment: @Bharatha зачем копировать самого себя. Я уже прочитал ниже всё это и ответил тебе. Тебе никто не мешает задать новый вопрос или отредактировать этот.

Comment: С нравственной точки зрения ты не прав, т.к. лишаешь меня возможности задать вопрос со всеми подробностями и получить на него ответ-решение.

Comment: @Bharatha не надоело? К сожалению давно заметил, кто часто говорит о нравственности и в жизни и здесь на сайте, на проверку оказывается сам... Надеюсь это к тебе не относится. Давай лучше поговорим на технические темы. Надеюсь модератор снесет этот офтопик. Или давай сами почистим офтопик. Согласен?

Answer (score 4):

Используется комбинация фильтров `feGaussianBlur` и  `feColorMatrix`
Можно настроить прозрачность размытия с помощью **feColorMatrix**. Значение 4-й строки, 4-го столбца - это множитель для исходного альфа-значения. Похоже, что 1,5x примерно подходит для вашего эффекта.

```html
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" style="margin:9px">
<defs>
 <filter id="blurAlpha">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0.5" />
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 
                                         0 1 0 0 0 
                                         0 0 1 0 0 
                                         0 0 0 1.5 0"/>
  </filter>

<symbol id="tt" viewBox="0 0 18 18" filter="url(#blurAlpha)"><path d="M8,2H9L15,8V9L9,15H8L2,9V8zM1,1L16,16M1,16L16,1" fill="none" stroke="#14c"/></symbol>
</defs>
<use href="#tt"/>
</svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Я тебе очень советую удалить этот вопрос потому что ты не понимая всех тонкостей моих задач не знаешь всей сути. Я хочу сам задать этот вопрос. И такой фильтр я уже применял. Он мне не подходит, т.к. линии сильно размыты и их не видно во всех браузерах на Blink движке, если залить голубым цветом середину. Так что пожалуйста удали вопрос, а я его задам от себя. Благодарю за помощь, время и понимание.

Comment: @Bharatha я написал в вопросе, всё что ты написал в чате, приложил твои картинки, твой код, я попросил тебя задать вопрос, ты не ответил, я тебе послал код ты не ответил. И тут такие претензии, ничего я удалять не буду, хочешь правь вопрос, хочешь давай свой ответ!

Comment: я не знал когда ты мне ответишь и намеревался сам задать этот вопрос. И ты мог бы меня спросить прежде чем его задавать. Это очень некрасиво так себя вести!

Comment: @Bharatha как некрасиво вести, типа украл твой вопрос? Ты не ответил **дважды** на моё предложение задать самому вопрос, я однозначно понял это, как твоё нежелание задать вопрос. А теперь выясняется, что ты ждал, когда я решу проблему, чтобы задать вопрос? Это звучит несерьезно.  Я сейчас добавлю в вопрос ссылку на переписку в SVG-чате и укажу источник вопроса. Вот только с этим согласен, что это моё упущение. Впредь попрошу ставить задачу более конкретно, а то видите ли не работает, если середину залить голубым. Где об этом шла речь??

Comment: Посмотри на своё «решение» при `width="18" height="18"` – во всех браузерах на Blink движках вообще нет ни капли размытия. А у тебя размытие здесь только потому, что ты картинку увеличил в три раза. А при `width="18" height="18"` линии сильно размыты и их не видно в середине во всех браузерах на Blink движке, если залить голубым цветом середину при stdDeviation="0.8" так как раньше размытие вообще не сработает во всех браузерах на Blink движке. Так что лучше удали свой вопрос – не продолжай портить и себе и мне настроение.

Comment: @Bharatha Исправил, размытие в Chrome есть. Нажми, несколько раз CTRL+ Так и ответ был направлен на это, чтобы размытие было одинаково во всех браузерах при дробных значениях   stdDeviation < 0.7  Нужно большее размытие, увеличь коэффициент. И ещё раз повторяю, где было хоть одно словечко про  `"если залить голубым цветом середину"` И ещё раз повторюсь, не нравится вопрос-ответ, задай свой вопрос. Если поставят дубликат, то я дубликат сниму, есть у меня права на это.

Comment: Я не ждал, когда ты решишь мою задачу, чтобы задать вопрос, потому что уже понял по твоему ответу, что не решишь. Я просто не успел тебе ответить. У меня есть и другие дела к сожалению! И к вопросу надо готовиться, и учитывать все тонкости – поэтому мне надо много времени, чтобы его задать. А у тебя в чате стоит в описании «Скорая помощь SVG», вот я и думал, что по-быстрому мне поможешь.

Comment: Размытия нет до 0.8! Если несколько раз нажать CTRL+, то будет размытие за счёт увеличения картинки браузером. Неужели тебе не видно на `width="18" height="18"` что нет размытия? Что касается прав на снятие дубликатов, то в правилах стоит, что модератор может забрать это право, если им неправильно пользуются. Поэтому я ещё раз прошу – не порти нам обоим конец дня и настроение и удали вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Bharatha viewBox не меняется, значит не меняется физический размер картинки. Просто на мелкой картинке его не видно из-за зрения. Вообще вопрос утопия, трудно поймать грань, размытия для мелких деталей  feGaussianBlur он работает грубо и очень по разному в разных браузерах. Сейчас готовлю новый ответ с новым набором фильтров и голубой серединкой

Comment: Если viewBox не меняется, то физический размер картинки не меняется только в том случае, если его не увеличивать другим способом.  А через увеличение размера листа в обозревателе ты увеличиваешь картинку, а следовательно и размытие добавляешь. Если смотреть через лупу (приложение) то видно, что размытия нет.

Comment: @Bharatha Физический размер картинки это размер, который нарисован в векторном редакторе. Проверь с помощью getBBox()  Как бы ты не увеличивал визуальный размер картинки с помощью scale()  или с помощью width height svg или с помощью изменения родительского контейнера, физический размер останется тот же 15x15px  Напиши разные варианты и посмотри результаты getBBox()

Comment: Мы сейчас говорим о размытии. Под увеличением размера картинки я имею ввиду её видоизменения на экране – это для меня её физический размер. А viewBox  –  это её изначальный размер. То что делает getBBox() вообще не важно в данном вопросе.

Comment: @Bharatha ты случайно SVG с растровыми изображениями не путаешь?  Это для png важен размер при визуализации. А в SVG, что 15px, что 15 км, выглядеть в смысле рендеринга будет одинаково. Поэтому и называется - `S` масштабируемая  `V` - векторная  `G` графика

Comment: Ты же сам видел, что при width="54" height="54" наступает размытие. Значит не всё так однозначно в этом вопросе.

Comment: @Bharatha я и при 18px вижу размытие. Это зависит от многих факторов - OC, версии браузера, видеокарты. И вот, что я сейчас подумал, ты же можешь задать этот вопрос на enSO интересно же, как там ответят. Там очень крутые ребята по SVG, некоторые из них даже работают по поддержке SVG в браузерах.

Comment: Да, мне и так ясно, что надо его там задавать. Тебя же на всякий случай об этом предупреждаю :-) Но мне бы очень хотелось сначала тут его задать.

Comment: Да здравствует ссоры !!! И брат пошел на брата ...

Comment: @Leks тебе показалось насчёт ссор. Это был спор на технические темы, а в споре, как известно рождается истина. Надеюсь, что Bharatha опубликует свой вопрос здесь или на enSO и получит нужное ему решение